# C# Windows Service keeps file locked using FlatDocument an example from MSDN "Find and Replace text in a Word document"

Tags: c#, windows-services, openxml

I have a Windows Service to copy files to a folder and replace Text in Word documents. For the replace in the documents I use this code: [Find and Replace text in a Word document](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Find-and-Replace-text-in-a-296bf75c/sourcecode?fileId=159173&pathId=576885184)

The problem is: The files stay in use until I copy the next files to another folder (and fill out Word document).

My code for the Search and Replace looks like this:

```
using (var flatDocument = new FlatDocument(fullpath))
{
    flatDocument.FindAndReplace("ValueA", "ValueB");
    // Save document on Dispose.
}
```

if I Skip this code the Service runs fine and the Files are not in use after copy. How come it stays in use even after the using clause?
Maybe someone has a clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there might be a bug in the *Developer Center* Sample Code [Find and Replace text in a Word document](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Find-and-Replace-text-in-a-296bf75c/sourcecode?fileId=159173&pathId=576885184).

In short, its keeping the *File Handle* open by not calling `Dispose` on the Underlying `FileStream` in the `FlatDocument` class. This seems weird as you would think `Package.Dispose` would clean up this handle, yet it doesn't.

If you modify the code in the `FlatDocument` class (as i have done in the following), it should fix it

**In the constructor**

```
private Stream _stream; // Add this

public FlatDocument(Stream stream)
{
     if (stream == null)
     {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
     }

     _stream = stream; // Add this

     documents = XDocumentCollection.Open(stream);
     ranges = new List<FlatTextRange>();

     CreateFlatTextRanges();
}
```

**In Dispose**

```
public void Dispose()
  {
     documents.Dispose();
     _stream.Dispose(); // Add this
  }
```

Comment: But the stream is passed into the `XDocumentCollection` object which has it's own disposal method. That in turn is calling [`Package.Close()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.close(v=vs.110).aspx) at the appropriate time and that method claims to "Saves and closes the package plus all underlying part streams."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i know, but i just tested it and it dosnt close the handle, only when i dispose the stream. its weird

Comment: @MichaelRandall yes I saw the problem mentioned in the comments. Thanks Im trying the solution right now

Comment: @Friedlman nps, though im still going through the Microsoft Package  source to work out why